# Refreshing partial, while also changing URL to match

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Using partial view and a home controller action index of

```
    <div id="EventController">
<div class="row event">
    <div class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="row row-top-20-margin">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills" id="EventNavBar">
            <li><a href="" data-tab="EventCalendar" id="EventCalendar">Event Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubmitNewEvent" data-tab="SubmitNewEvents" id="SubmitNewEvent">Submit New Event</a></li>
            <li><a href="#MyEvents" data-tab="MyEvents" id="MyEvents">My Events</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 main">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="EventPartialReplace">
                    Loading...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var root = "/Event/Event";

    //Event Left Hand Nav
    $(document).on('click', '#EventNavBar li a', function(event) {
        $('#EventNavBar li.active').removeClass('active');
        var $this = $(event.currentTarget);
        $this.closest('li').addClass('active');
        var tab = $this.data('tab');
        var url =  root + '/Get'+ tab;
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: dataArray,
    success: function (data) {
        wasSuccessful = true;
        userFeedbackMessage = successMessage;
        resultData = data;

    },
    });
});

function EventTabCallBack(result) {
    $('#EventPartialReplace').html(result.responseText);
    return true;
}
```

I am them calling a ajax post to the Event Controller load the correct partial view inside . The event Controller returns partial view html and i do an html.replace on the div. Which works, but if i wanted the url to change with the partial replace how would i achieve that.

Currently it just appends the  to the end of the URL "Event/Home/Index#EventCalendar" when i would like it to replace the URL with something like "Event/EventCalendar"

I have tried location.hash but it still appends and wont work for direct links - so if a user enters root/Event/EventCalendar into the url it should open the home index with the nav-pill active and the partial view showing, instead of just selecting the nav

Comment: Take a look at [History API](http://html5demos.com/history).

Comment: But you can't direct link to http://html5demos.com/history/first and get a page. Would this be possible?

Comment: Then you would need to set up an actual page that services that URL when the user reloads or types that route directly. If you have lots of these examples in your application you may want to consider a SPA framework like Angular to do this for you.